# Python unittest - The file specified must still be importable as a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am reading [Python `unittest` command line interface docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface). It says:

> Test modules can be specified by file path as well:
>
> `python -m unittest tests/test_something.py`
>
> This allows you to use the shell filename completion to specify the test module. The file specified must still be importable as a module. The path is converted to a module name by removing the `.py` and converting path separators into `.`. If you want to execute a test file that isn’t importable as a module you should execute the file directly instead.

I know that a `*.py` file is a module. So what is the meaning of:

> The file specified must still be importable as a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually three different ways to define a module in Python:

- A module can be written in Python itself.
- A module can be written in C and loaded dynamically at run-time, like the re (regular expression) module.
- A built-in module is intrinsically contained in the interpreter, like the `collections` module.

A module’s contents are accessed the same way in all three cases: with the import statement.

All you need to do to build a module and make it importable is create a file that contains *legitimate* Python code and then give the file a name with a `.py` extension. That’s it!

No special syntax or voodoo is necessary.

You can find more on modules in [Python's official docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)